# Wordpress - if there are no posts to display for a single category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I try to display a message if there are no posts for a certain category

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=9&showposts=10");
     while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But when I add an 'else', I get the blank screen

```
<?php else: ?>
message ////
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this 
    `<?php
    if ( have_posts() )
    {
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            // Your loop code
        endwhile;
    }
    else {
            echo  'Sorry, no posts were found';
          }
    ?>`